# You are alone on Earth. You are immortal. You are tasked to destroy all traces of civilization as quick as possible. What do you do?

Tags: earth, civilization, immortality

You are alone on Earth. You are immortal. You are tasked to destroy all traces of civilization as quick as possible. What should you do to complete the task quicker?

Comment: At modern level of technology, lone human in 1000 years would be still chipping at old buildings with a stone mallet. In 100,000 years, there still would be lot of civilization remains buried, but this human would lack any means of traveling to and locating those remains.

Comment: I am a trace of civilization myself, so I guess I can't complete the task

Comment: Ugh, peat bogs! Marshes! Darn it!

Comment: I'm inclined to say "let them do it themselves", but the question seems rather vague to me.  What tech do I have ?  Am I human looking ?  Tasked by who and by what deadline ?  In secret ?  Is the planet to be inhabitable for mortals afterwards ?  Please expand your question with detail.

Comment: Does the satellites in orbit, the things left behind in the Moon, and the probes and rovers sent all over the solar system count? 

What about the Voyager?

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, you would have to destroy everything within a current ~10000 light-year radius from Earth, but which expands at the speed of light. Without FTL, it's impossible.

Comment: @Aidan F. Pierce no, you have to destroy only things on Earth surface.

Comment: @Sasha no, you have to destroy only things on Earth surface.

Comment: @StephenG you can use any tech left by humanity on Earth (if you can use it alone). Yes, you are human-looking.

Comment: Nuking everything would be definitely faster than deconstructing and burying every part of Earth covered by buildings, roads or plots.

Comment: start eating earth ..since your immortal nothing will happen to you ..when you finish eating the entire earth .. nothing will exist to prove earth existed..